# Is there a problem with my Negamax implementation?

Tags: rust, chess, negamax

I'm trying to write a simple negamax algorithm in Rust for my Chess engine. I have a very simple evaluation function:

```
pub fn evaluate(&self) -> i32 {
    let mut eval: i32 = 0;

    for piece_type in PType::PIECE_TYPES {
        eval += (
            self.bitboards[piece_type, Col::White].count_ones() as i32 - 
            self.bitboards[piece_type, Col::Black].count_ones() as i32
        ) * piece_type.value();
    }

    eval
}
```

And here's my negamax implementation:

```
fn negamax(pos: &mut Position, depth: u32, piece_colour: Col) -> i32 {
    let mult = match piece_colour {
        Col::Black => -1,
        Col::White => 1
    };

    if depth == 0 {
        return pos.evaluate() * mult
    }

    let mut best_so_far = -9999;

    let legal_moves = movegen::legal_moves(pos, piece_colour);

    for child in legal_moves {
        pos.make_move(child);
        best_so_far = std::cmp::max(best_so_far, negamax(pos, depth - 1, piece_colour.inverse()));
        pos.unmake_move(child);
    }

    -best_so_far
}
```

A lot of this is derived from the Wikipedia pseudocode for the Negamax algorithm. However, in the following position on depth 5, the best move generated for white is Nxd3 when it should be Nb7 to fork the queen and king, then capture the queen on the next move (yes, my move generator does account for forks).

[image: The position in question]

I have a feeling my Negamax implementation is at fault, however I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pseudocode given in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax) which you followed is wrong: There is a discrepancy between `depth == 0` and `depth > 0`. In the `depth == 0` case, it returns the evaluation from the point of view of the current player. But for `depth > 0`, it returns the evaluation from the point of view of the other player due to the negation at the end. This causes incorrect results when going from depth 1 to 0.

To fix this, the negation should be done right after the recursive call instead of when returning. Note that this is the way it's done in the pseudocode for the alpha-beta pruning variant which seems correct.

There are also some additional issues in your code:

- You don't detect stalemate. Currently when there are no legal moves you return -9999 (assuming you make the fix above first), which can indicate that the current player was checkmated. But another possibility is stalemate which should have a score of 0.
- All "mate in N" positions will have the same score of 9999, which means the AI will be in no rush to mate and may just make repeating moves. One way to solve this is to give "mate in N" a score of 9999-N.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Moving the negation to just after the recursive call seemed to help a lot, however, it's now making the move ne6, forking the King and the Rook, instead of the King and the Queen (Negamax evaluates both moves to have equal scores of `-19`). I'm confused as to how it can know to fork and yet somehow get the wrong piece.

Comment: @BenTechy66 After Nb7, Kc7, Nxa5, Rb4, the knight is trapped and then captured, leading to stalemate which your code regards as being checkmated.

Comment: Interesting, you could be correct. However, even on low depths (d=3), it plays the move, despite the fact it shouldn't be able to see the stalemate.